# Weird text wrapping differences between browsers

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

Trying to debug a bigger problem I managed to reduce it to this simple situation:

Here it is in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uUGp6/

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <img class="pic" src="http://i3.minus.com/jbuwgurDfNniFM.png"/>
    Test 1
    this is a test: testa testb testc testd teste
</div>

<div class="divider"/></div>

<div class="box">
    <img class="pic" src="http://i3.minus.com/jbuwgurDfNniFM.png"/>
    Test 2<br/>
    this is a test testa testb testc testd teste
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.box {
    background-color: beige;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: 100px;
}

.pic {
    float: left;
}

.divider {
    clear:both;
    height:10px;
    width:500px;
    background:blue;
}
```

In Firefox,Chrome and Safari the text in the second box is wrapped. A new line starts after "testc"
However in Opera, IE9, IE8 there is no wrapping.

The only difference between the two boxes is the br tag in the second one.

I don't understand why in the second box the line gets wrapped but in the first box a much bigger line is not wrapped. And what does the br tag have to do with it? Does anyone know what I can do to force the browsers to display it in the same way?

Also, which browsers get it right?

P.S.

The floats are essential (like i said, this is a simplification of a bigger problem).

I should add that I'm testing this on Windows 7

Edit: it wraps in Safari as well

Comment: Can you not give the `.box` a width? That should force the wrap. Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AYBmc/) that demonstrates.  Works in IE9 and Opera.

Comment: @Scott No, in the actual site the designers want the boxes to adjust their width according to the text inside them. They also want the text to remain as much as possible on a single line (unwrapped), which is what brought me here.

Comment: In that case, just drop your `<br />` tag and you get your desired results.

Comment: @Scott The content of the boxes is saved in the backend with an editor, so I don't have control over what that content is. Also, it doesn't have to be a br. H1 creates the same problem: http://jsfiddle.net/47w5t/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap the content that is pulled from the DB after the floated `img` element in an `inline-block` `div` (or `span` if you can't use `div`) the problem will be solved. Even if you have `<br>` or `<h1>`... tags in the pulled content from the DB.

So your sample code will look like this:

```
<div class="box">
 <img class="pic" src="http://i3.minus.com/jbuwgurDfNniFM.png"/>
 <div class="DBContentWrapper">
  Test 1
  this is a test: testa testb testc testd teste
 </div>
</div>

<div class="divider"/></div>

<div class="box">
 <img class="pic" src="http://i3.minus.com/jbuwgurDfNniFM.png"/>
 <div class="DBContentWrapper">
   Test 2<br/>
   this is a test testa testb testc testd teste
 </div>
</div>
```

/\

```
.box {
    background-color: beige;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: 100px;
}

.DBContentWrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}

.pic {
    float: left;
}

.divider {
    clear:both;
    height:10px;
    width:500px;
    background:blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I'll mark it as accepted because it works well and it can help other people. Unfortunatelly for me, the image is part of the DB content, so I can't do that...

Answer (score 0):

if you define the white-space attribute to e.g. pre-wrap, you will have the same wrapping in all browsers and you can drop the `<br />` tag...

```
.box { white-space: pre-wrap; }
```

Comment: That would leave me with weird spaces in the text (the content of the boxes is edited by the sute admins in the backend and then pulled from the database into my file)

Comment: Do the text from the database contain html-tags for every line break? I would have expected the text to be void of html...

Comment: Also, H1 seems to create the same problem:  jsfiddle.net/47w5t/1

Comment: yes, all tags incurring a line break will give you extra spaces when combined with pre-wrap. Pre-wrap should mainly be used for text that is not structured with html tags (p, h1, h2, br etc)....